# BI Publisher - Can't implement cursor logic inside data model

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bi-publisher

I want to use cursor logic inside the data model's script in order to select some data from tables based on different conditions, but I can't do it from the data model's query script also I can't invoke already stored procedure from db,  is there any better option to accomplish this

here are options that I have already tried but got some errors:

1. I have tried to create procedure and then invoke it  from data model as well but it is not possible to call procedure from inside data model's script  and i need to reflect procedure's data into data model structure, so i belive this scenario is not good for me.
2. I have used following solution Anonymous blocks (Procedural Call) data model in Oracle BI Publisher (Oracle Fusion):http://oracleappssolutiions.blogspot.com/2020/12/anonymous-blocks-procedural-call-data.html  it is perfect when we need simple 'select' but can't run more complicated logic like this:

> ```
> DECLARE
> type refcursor is REF CURSOR;
> xdo_cursor refcursor;
> BEGIN
> OPEN :xdo_cursor FOR 
>    FOR c IN (select t.* from test t where t.VERSION=2) LOOP
>        FOR d in (select c.* from record d where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 0 start with d.id. = c.id connect  by prior d.id = c.id) loop
>      select * test
>        where id=d.id
>      end loop;
>    END LOOP; 
> END;
> ```

when i trying to run this i am getting similar errors:
[image]

Please share your thoughts/Ideas

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use a cursor? Can it not be handled with unions and where clauses?

Comment: I have never worked with OBI, but I have quite a lot of experience in other reporting tools. What I assume the issue here is that OBI wants a query or a procedure. I am going off of speculation, but most Oracle tools allow you to create procedures as a programming unit. You can always make an out parameter in the procedure in the form of a sys_refcursor, which will most likely "trick" OBI into thinking it's a regular query. This is my speculation, I will remove the comment if you will correct me.

Comment: @EdHayes3 I thought it would be more structured and simple way to use cursors (for creating loop logic) for setup hierarchy structure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try a Pipelined Table Function if you want to use a procedure to generate data.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm

2. If you can get away with just doing select statements with unions and where clause filters, that may be the cleanest way to go.
3. I'm not sure what the end goal is, but the grouping functionality for templates may help you. There's quite a bit of documentation in the user guides. look for `for-each-group` in the guide. It's used to take a single flat series of rows/elements, and then create a hierarchy of them, on the fly.